# Простейшая кодировка букв

Tags: java, массивы

Пишу прогу, которая принимает строку(только буквы, никаких знаков препинания и цифр) и целое число, насколько передвинуть символы сроки по ASCII таблице. Ничего сложного. Но! Также ***нельзя***, чтобы в результате использовались цифры и прочие знаки препинания. Например,
дана "**XYZ**" и ее нужно передвинуть на 3 символа= "**ABC**", а не "[/]" 
"**xYZ**" = "**aBC**", а не "{/]" т.е. алфавит должен идти "колесом" :[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То же касается и прописных букв.

Прошу дать совет или напутствие, как подойди к решению!
Сделал пока вот :

```
  public class Coder {

    String  ABC = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    String abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

      public String coding(String gap, int n){
          String output="";
          for (int i = 0; i < gap.length(); i++) {

              char c = gap.charAt(i);
              c+=n;
              output+=c;
          }
          return output;
      }

}
```

Comment: Массив символов, где будут сначала идти большие буквы, а потом маленькие. Потом по этому массиву искать нужный символ (`indexOf()`, если будет все в строке) и менять его в результирующей строке.

Comment: Строки abcd... не нужны. Используйте коды символов. Берете код (приведение символа к int судя по интернету), убеждаетесь что он входит в большие (65-90) или маленькие (97-122). Вычитаете код первой буквы диапазона (65/122) - получили номер буквы в алфавите. Прибавляете смещение, берете остаток от деления на 26 (кол-во букв) - получили номер буквы в новой системе, прибавляете первую букву, получаете символ из кода

Comment: Спасибо за такой подход. Я не понял "Прибавляете смещение, берете остаток от деления на 26 (кол-во букв)...". То есть, если у меня буква "Y" и n=3, то  остаток (26%3) = 2. Затем я прибавляю к букве "A" это двойку. так :?

Comment: имеется ввиду для больших будет  `output += (char) (((с - 65 + n) % 26) + 65);` и для маленьких `output += (char) (((с - 97 + n) % 26) + 97);`  А `с` - это ваша `char c = gap.charAt(i);`

Comment: @Chubatiy Получается , что я могу перевести строку либо только с большими буквами либо только с маленькими ? А если будет микс ?

Comment: Нет. Просто надо добавить перед перекодированием проверку, в какой диапазон попадает ваш код сивола. Ели @Mike не против, добавлю в свой ответ. Добавил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так

```
String abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

public String coding(String gap, int n) {
    String output = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < gap.length(); i++) {
        //Получаем тек. букву
        String currentLetter = gap.substring(i, i + 1);
        //получаем её индекс
        int indexOf = abc.indexOf(currentLetter.toLowerCase());
        //считаем индекс с учяетом смещения
        int nextIndex = getNextIndex(indexOf, n);
        //получаем букву со смещением
        String cryptedLetter = abc.substring(nextIndex, nextIndex + 1);
        //добавляем в выходное значение
        output
                += //если тек. буква равна ей же в нижнем регистре
                (currentLetter.equals(currentLetter.toLowerCase()))
                //пишем как есть
                ? cryptedLetter
                //иначе получается, что изначально буква была в верхнем регистре
                : cryptedLetter.toUpperCase();

    }
    return output;
}

public int getNextIndex(int curr, int offset) {
    //Если тек. индекс + смещение не превышаем длинну строки
    return (curr + offset <= abc.length() - 1)
            //так и оставляем
            ? curr + offset
            //иначе расчитываем смещение
            : (curr + offset) - abc.length() - 1;
}
```

Или как советовал в комментариях **Mike**

```
public String coding(String gap, int n) {
        String output = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < gap.length(); i++) {
            char charAt = gap.charAt(i);
            if (charAt >= 65 && charAt <= 90) {
                output += (char) (((charAt - 65 + n) % 26) + 65);
            } else if (charAt >= 97 && charAt <= 122) {
                output += (char) (((charAt - 97 + n) % 26) + 97);
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Comment: getNextIndex => `(curr + offset) % abc.length()`

Comment: да, пытался максимально расписать для наглядности